# How to run multiple APScheduler tasks in flask in parallel?

Tags: flask, apscheduler

I am trying to build a Flask app to automate the process of scraping certain websites. I am using APScheduler to schedule the scraping functions.

The app works fine with just one scheduler, but when I add a second one the tasks won't run. There's no error messages, nothing.

Does anyone know what could be causing this? I have also read about about task queues... how would one go about setting up a task queue while using APScheduler?

Comment: Thank you for your question! Could you edit the question and provide some minimal sample code for others to reproduce your issue? Also, by any chance do [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32469112/how-to-run-concurrent-ap-scheduler-jobs) help?